# Testing for multiple conditional heteroskedasticity in multivariate regression

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, multivariate-analysis, breusch-pagan

Briefly, I am looking for an extension of the Breusch-Pagan test to the case of multivariate dependent variables. The *scalar* form of the test, with multiple regressors, assumes the model
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y &= \vec{\beta}^{\top} \vec{x} + \epsilon,\\
\epsilon^2 &= h(\vec{z}^{\top}\vec{\alpha}),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the first element of $\vec{z}$ is identically one, and $h$ is some known function with first and second derivatives. The test is of the null hypothesis
$$
H_0: \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = \ldots = \alpha_p = 0.
$$

I am curious about the case where one is performing *multivariate* multiple linear regression, with vector $\vec{y}$. Are there known tests for this?

Comment: Recalling that in econometrics multivariate linear regressions are called seemingly unrelated regression models, Google Scholar searches immediately become bounteous.